# TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable | Python3

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, pyrogram

**▶️ Code :**

```
photos = client.get_profile_photos("me")

await client.delete_profile_photos([p.file_id for p in photos[1:]])
```

**▶️ Output / TraceBack :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/plugins/code_runner.py", line 44, in eval
    await aexec(cmd, client, message)
  File "/plugins/code_runner.py", line 71, in aexec
    return await locals()["__aexec"](client, message)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __aexec
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried many times, for examples:

`(await client.delete_profile_photos([p.file_id for p in photos[1:]]))`

`await client.delete_profile_photos([async p.file_id for p in photos[2:]])`

and many more,

but i can't figure it out, i'm noob so i hope someone can help me with this..

Comment: maybe `photos = await client.get_profile_photos("me")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't `await`ed the first call, `get_profile_photos`. So it's the coroutine, not the result.